# setting up maxmert kit, including the css files

Tags: css, frameworks, css-frameworks, maxmertkit

has anyone used Maxmertkit ? They say in documentation that you have to include some css files, but I cant find them in the package i've downloaded. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Sass: Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets, are included.

Download it from [github](https://github.com/maxmert/maxmertkit)

[Sass Installation](http://sass-lang.com/install)

[Sass Basics](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Or if you don't want to do all these, you can convert your sass to css from [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/), just copy your sass in css column and click the eye (shown in image) to compile it in css.

[image]

Comment: How do I include sass files ?

Comment: How do I import all that files ?

Answer (score 0):

There is new version 1.0.5: http://maxmert.com/start.

You can use CDN to include css (don't forget to change `{{version}}`):

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/maxmertkit/{{version}}/css/maxmertkit.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/maxmertkit/{{version}}/js/maxmertkit.js"></script>
```